# Родительская запись у своего типа поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Никак не могу добиться выбора родителя для произвольного типа поста в wp.
Вот типа поста что есть. Нужно - возможность создания дочерних.

```
    register_post_type('services', array(
        'label' => null,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Услуги', // основное название для типа записи
            'singular_name' => 'Услуги', // название для одной записи этого типа
            'add_new' => 'Добавить Услуги', // для добавления новой записи
            'add_new_item' => 'Добавление Услуги', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
            'edit_item' => 'Редактирование Услуги', // для редактирования типа записи
            'new_item' => 'Новая Услуги', // текст новой записи
            'view_item' => 'Смотреть Услуги', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
            'search_items' => 'Искать Услуги', // для поиска по этим типам записи
            'not_found' => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
            'parent_item_colon' => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
            'menu_name' => 'Услуги', // название меню
            'featured_image' => 'Картинка',
// Миниатюра записи
            'set_featured_image' => 'Добавить картинку',
// Установить миниатюру записи
            'remove_featured_image' => 'Удалить картинку',
// Удалить миниатюру записи
            'use_featured_image' => 'Использовать картинку',
// Использовать как миниатюру записи
        ),
        'description' => '',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true, // по умолчанию значение show_in_menu
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
        'rest_base' => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
        'menu_position' => 2,
        'menu_icon' => "dashicons-admin-collapse",
        //'capability_type'   => 'post',
        //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
        //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','revisions'), // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
        /*'taxonomies' => array("slide_position"),*/
        'has_archive' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    ));
```

Comment: Расширьте свой вопрос, добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в свойство **supports** нужно добавить '**page-attributes**',
свойство **hierarchical** как у меня **true**